# Updating specifics rows in a RecordSource of a Sub-Form by using textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am on Office Access 2007, i've been working on a Race Timer for school during vacations.
I already know that Access is not the best for this sort of software but the previous developer been using this..

So here's the problem.
I've got a form, which contain a sub-form. That sub-form have a RecordSource, that is generating lines in the body/mid(?) section of the sub-form. Each fields are put in a textbox exept the name.
I want to change for instance the second row, by modifying the textbox related to it and clicking on a button i placed in the footer section to update the Table connected to the RecordSource.

But i have no idea how i can know with programmation how to access to the textbox of the the third row, cause they have same name?

Best Regards

I can mail you an image of what it looks like if needed (i am under 10 reputations so no images : / )

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to understand exactly what you are looking for, but you could likely do the following;

> > Dim dbCurr As DAO.Database
> >     Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
> >     Set dbCurr = CurrentDb
> >     Set rst = dbCurr.OpenRecordset("NameOfTableRecordsetIsReferencing")
> >
> > With rst
> >        .Edit
> >        !ContactName = txtName                 ..........' This can be any field in your table
> >        .Update
> >     End With
> >
> > rst.Close
> >     dbCurr.Close